# Keyboard detection on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard

I tried to implement keyboard detection on canvas. Basically, i just wanna move my rectangle to the right and the left sides by x :) Here is my code where I added fucntion player and object player, and also Event Listener.

```
function Player() {
    this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = 50, this.h = 50;
    this.render = function () {

        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }

}
```

However, it does not show anything! everything is gone. Whats happened? I think I am using Event listener right...Any help will appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although mark's answer is accepted and correct in principle you should be aware of some issues you may run into using that code (was too many points to fit in a comment so here's an optional answer):

- You should prefer `event.keyCode` instead of `event.which` (which is deprecated - see what I did there?... :-O ) (and there is `event.key` which will be more common in the future ).
- With the `keypress` event you won't be able to detect *arrow* keys in some browser, use `keydown` event instead if that is needed.
- In older IE versions the event object is only available from `window.event` (hardly a problem if you require canvas and therefor a more modern version, but if you want to support older IE using for example exCanvas then you would want to consider this as well).

So a more robust approach would be:

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {

    /// make sure we have an event object
    e = e || windows.event;

    /// prefer keyCode over which if available
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    /// if you use the key, you can chose to prevent the default action
    /// on the key (ie. if you use page down you probably want to prevent
    /// browser window from scrolling down etc.)

    ... check keyCode here ...

    if (keyCode === someCode) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

        ... action here ...

        return false;
    }
}
```

My 3.5 cents..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that as part of your Java + HTML5 game, you have a gameloop? if not look into requestAnimationFrame or the likes of setInterval() setTimeout() no game can function properly without a game loop.

ah yes another thing, when accepting keyboard input use keycodes 
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes